# cannot assign to variable with const-qualified type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Im trying to change the value of SWSegueFrontIdentifier dynamically as follows because the the front views are dynamic. Following is my code

```
if ([prefs boolForKey:@"isDashboardAvailable"])
{
    SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @"sw_front";          
} else {
    SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @"sw_second_front";
}
```

but im getting the following error

> Cannot assign to variable 'SWSegueFrontIdentifier' with
>   const-qualified type 'NSString *const __strong'

why am I getting this error? How can I be able to change the SWSegueFrontIdentifier value?

Comment: why dont you adopt this logic in loadStoryBoardControllers method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want it to be dynamic front view controller, try the following..

create another const variable as following

`NSString * const SWSegueSecondFrontIdentifier = @"sw_second_front";`

then  implement the following code in  `loadStoryboardControllers` method

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     if ([prefs boolForKey:@"isDashboardAvailable"])
     {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueSecondFrontIdentifier sender:nil];
     } else {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueFrontIdentifier sender:nil];
     }
```

revert back if you have any difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

Your question it self give you answer. You are trying to change the value of `constant`, it is not possible, you can't change the value of constants. If you want to change the value of `SWSegueFrontIdentifier` declare is as variable not constant like this

```
NSString *SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @""; 
if ([prefs boolForKey:@"isDashboardAvailable"])
{
    SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @"sw_front";
} 
else {
    SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @"sw_second_front";
}
```